# Asp.net Routing multi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want routing url below

> url/category-code  ex : url/luxury ; url/normal ; url/sedan

and post detail

> url/post-detail-code  ex: url/honda-civic-20-review

and brand url

> url/brand-code   ex: url/toyota ; url/hyndai ; url/lexus

Here is the route configuration

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "postdetail",
   "{SeoFriendlyUrl}",
   defaults: new { controller = "PostDetail", action = "Index", SeoFriendlyUrl = UrlParameter.Optional },
   namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "postcategory",
   "{SeoFriendlyUrl}",
   new { controller = "PostCategory", action = "Index",SeoFriendlyUrl = UrlParameter.Optional  },
   namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);



routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
    namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Route templates need to be unique to avoid route conflicts

```
//url/details/honda-civic-20-review
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "postdetail",
   url: "details/{SeoFriendlyUrl}",
   defaults: new { controller = "PostDetail", action = "Index", SeoFriendlyUrl = UrlParameter.Optional },
   namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);

//url/categories/luxury
//url/categories/normal
//url/categories/sedan    
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "postcategory",
   url: "categories/{SeoFriendlyUrl}",
   defaults: new { controller = "PostCategory", action = "Index",SeoFriendlyUrl = UrlParameter.Optional  },
   namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);

//url/brands/toyota
//url/brands/hyndai
//url/brands/lexus    
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "brand",
   url: "brands/{SeoFriendlyUrl}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Brands", action = "Index",SeoFriendlyUrl = UrlParameter.Optional  },
   namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
    namespaces: new[] { "RiviWeb.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: i want sort url, and seo friendly